# How to make a file invisible in Finder using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, file

I need to hide the file in finder as well as in spotlight if possible using objective-c or using C calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the invisibility attribute through some C calls. This is pretty raw code that only works on some file systems and is missing error checking.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/attr.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/vnode.h>

typedef struct attrlist attrlist_t;

struct FInfoAttrBuf {
    u_int32_t length;
    fsobj_type_t objType;

    union {
        char rawBytes[32];

        struct {
            FileInfo info;
            ExtendedFileInfo extInfo;
        } file;

        struct {
            FolderInfo info;
            ExtendedFolderInfo extInfo;
        } folder;
    } finderInfo;
};
typedef struct FInfoAttrBuf FInfoAttrBuf;


static int SetFileInvisibility(const char *path, int isInvisible) {
    attrlist_t attrList;
    FInfoAttrBuf attrBuf;

    memset(&attrList, 0, sizeof(attrList));
    attrList.bitmapcount = ATTR_BIT_MAP_COUNT;
    attrList.commonattr  = ATTR_CMN_OBJTYPE | ATTR_CMN_FNDRINFO;

    int err = getattrlist(path, &attrList, &attrBuf, sizeof(attrBuf), 0);
    if (err != 0)
        return errno;

    // attrBuf.objType = (VREG | VDIR), inconsequential for invisibility

    UInt16 flags = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(attrBuf.finderInfo.file.info.finderFlags);

    if (isInvisible)
        flags |= kIsInvisible;
    else
        flags &= (~kIsInvisible);

    attrBuf.finderInfo.file.info.finderFlags = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(flags);

    attrList.commonattr = ATTR_CMN_FNDRINFO;
    err = setattrlist(path, &attrList, attrBuf.finderInfo.rawBytes, sizeof(attrBuf.finderInfo.rawBytes), 0);

    return err;
}
```

or you can go through `NSURL` if you can target Snow Leopard which abstracts away how each file system processes and handles extended attributes.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[url setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsHiddenKey error:NULL];
```

Comment: Thanks for the code,I'll try to implement the code in my app if possible. As i need to take care of any kind incompatibility in the app.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
chflags("/path/to/file", UF_HIDDEN);
```

to hide any file.

See [man chflags(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chflags.2.html) for more.

Answer (score 3):

(EDIT: Leading dot doesn't seem to keep it out of mdfind)

Files that begin with a "." will be hidden in Finder by default. Users can override that with a `defaults` key, but this will take care of it in general.

For Spotlight, see [TA24975](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA24975), which explains in more detail what Lyndsey mentions. You probably need to combine the approaches, depending on whether you're trying to avoid `mdfind -name` from picking it up.

Comment: Thanks, i am wondering is there any Finder API can be use to set the hidden flag. i was searching how to use the Finder API's flag kIsInvisible and how can be use to set the invisible flag for particulatr file.

Comment: AmitSri: It's part of the file's catalog info. Use `FSGetCatalogInfo` to get the file's Finder `FileInfo` structure (declared in the catalog-info structure as an array of bytes, for some reason), set the invisible bit and clear the inited bit, then use `FSSetCatalogInfo` to apply that change.