# Saving User's Coin Count

Tags: cocoa, encryption, persistence

While my app is not a game, a coin-based game works as a good analogy.

In a game like this, the user has a certain number of coins that they can earn through gameplay or by purchasing an IAP. The main problem is securely storing how many coins the user has locally.

I know there are other questions like this, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577458/2035473). This answer basically says, there is no use in trying to save data securely; just deal with the fact that users can edit the data.

I would rather not just leave the data out in the open for users to change (if they can edit the data, why would they purchase an IAP?). I have looked into the Keychain, which has a public interface to view and edit the data, and NSUserDefaults, which saves to a Plist that can easily be changed.

Is there a better option for me, or should I just not even try (like the answer above suggests)?

**Edit**: The app is actually a developer tool that has a limited number of tokens. Because the users all have technical skills, the majority of them (I assume) have enough knowledge to find and change the Plist file or the Keychain data.

Comment: It might be helpful to expand on what threat model you are working from. How motivated are users to bypass this controls, what does it really cost you if they do so, how easily does any such exploit spread to other users? How many aspects of this currency do you really need to guard and how strongly? (Your controls might be bypassed by editing the available number of coins, or by preventing the app from decrementing that number, or by skipping the check for those coins entirely, or by reverting to a older state after spending a coin...)

Comment: @Jonah The app is a translator for iOS developers (lets developers easily translate a Localizable.strings file). For every characters translated is a token deducted from the user. The user has incentive to refill their tokens so they can continue to translate more characters. If they can edit the Plist, they can simply add more later manually instead of through IAPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me very well. Try this: https://github.com/nielsmouthaan/SecureNSUserDefaults. It will store encrypted bool/string/float/integer in your UserDefaults file. Hopefully this is what you want. Make sure you download and add [CocoaSecurity](https://github.com/kelp404/CocoaSecurity) to your project. CocoaSecurity is a required element of SecureNSUSerDefaults, so you do not need to import it into any of your files. You must also download [Base64](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64), which is a required element of CocoaSecurity. You also need to add Base64 to your project, but do not need to import it into any of your files.

**USAGE**

Import the header file anywhere you want to use the encryption method.

```
#import <SecureNSUserDefaults/NSUserDefaults+SecureAdditions.h>
```

Then, set an encryption key, *probably in your `awakeFromNib` method*:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setSecret:@"your_secret_goes_here"];
```

I recommend generating a random string of numbers and letters.
Then, you must store the information in your UserDefaults file.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    setSecretObject:@"your_secret_object"
    forKey:@"the_key_your_object_will be_stored_under"];
```

To retrieve the string, use this method:

```
NSString *retrievedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     
    secretStringForKey:@"the_key_your_object_will be_stored_under"];
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: By the way, what is the name of your application, and how could I get it when it is complete? I would be interested in using it!

Comment: I'll try this out. The app is called Local, and it's on the MAS under Developer Tools. But come to think of it... You know the vulnerability in the app. I'm watching you ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Yeah, but I won't be able to decrypt the data without your encryption key! Remember, this is where you set the encryption key: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setSecret:@"your_secret_goes_here"];`!

Comment: Also, it occurred to me that the user might still be able to change the preference in NSUserDefaults, try this solution out, but if it doesn't work I would suggest re-encrypting the data every time the user launches the app. Or, maybe store the data in two separate places (such as the secured NSUserDefaults file and a encrypted text document (storied in App Support)) and then matching them when the user launches the app, to see if the values are equal. If not, then set the app to re-encrypt the data with the lower value of the two, as the user would have only set one of the values as higher.